# reprobar vs desaprobar/suspender

Tags: sinónimos

Is there any difference between "reprobar" and "desaprobar" (Latin America)/"suspender" (Spain) when they mean "to fail" (a test, a course) ?

Example1:

- Reprobé el examen.
- Desaprobé/Suspendí el examen.

Example 2:

- Reprobé en Matemática(s).
- Desaprobé/Suspendí en Matemática(s).

Comment: In Colombia we rarely use "reprobar" but instead we say "**Perdí** el examen" or "Juan **perdió** matemáticas"

Comment: "perdí el examen" already means "I missed the test". If it can also mean "to fail an exam" in Colombia, doesn't it become "ambiguous" ?

Comment: Nop. It is not ambiguous because it does not mean "I missed the test" but only "I failed it". For us to say "I was late so I **missed** the test and because of that I **flunk** the course" we say "Llegué tarde y **me perdí** el examen y por eso **perdí** la materia"

Comment: I don't follow. If "perder el examen" cannot mean to miss the test", why have you just translated "I missed the test" as "me perdí el examen"?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista What DGaleano seems to mean is that with a dative "perder**se** el examen" means "miss the exam", but without the dative "perder el examen / la materia" means "fail an exam / a subject" (Colombian usage).

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks, @Gustavson!

Comment: @Gustavson thanks for the explanation. That is correct. Alan the difference between usages is on the **bold** bits of the sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Argentina, "reprobar" is slighly more formal than "desaprobar". We also have "bochar" (*flunk*), which is very informal and always used with "en X":

- Me bochó / Me bocharon en (el examen de) matemática.

Both "reprobar" and "desaprobar" (we don't use "suspender" with this meaning) are used transitively:

- Reprobé / Desaprobé (el examen de) matemática.
- Me reprobaron / Me desaprobaron en (el examen de) matemática.

For further reference, see http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=reprobar.

Although the intransitive use is not described in dictionaries, we can hear it, mainly with "desaprobar":

- Desaprobé en (el examen de) matemática.

"aprobar" can in fact be used intransitively (see: https://www.spanishdict.com/comparar/desaprobar/aprobar), in sentences like:

- Después de mucho trabajo arduo, por fin aprobé. (After a lot of hard work, I finally passed.)

so I see no reason for not using "desaprobar" intransitively, too.

Comment: Do all the points in your answer apply equally to failing a test (instead of a subject, eg math) ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Yes. I've added that to make it clearer.